# Transform for loop that concatenates tensor from pytorch to tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, signal-processing

I am trying to transform a python class that I will use in a project for splitting some tensors. Due to some other reasons I have to transform it from pytorch to tensorflow, but when doing this specific step indicated in the code below I get wrong results.

The pytorch code, when applied to a random tensor X with shape (1, 2, 2, 257) gives me a modified tensor with shape (1, 2, 128, 30). This result is correct, however, the modified tensorflow code gives me on the same tensor a shape (1, 2, 128, 237) instead, when the last item should be 30.

```
### Pytorch code
        def forward(self, X):

        B = torch.tensor_split(X, self.idxs, dim=3)
        Z = []

        for i, (layer_norm, linear_layer) in enumerate(zip(self.layer_norms, self.linear_layers)):
            b_i = torch.cat((B[i][:, :, 0, :, :],B[i][:, :, 1, :, :]), 2)
            b_i = torch.transpose(layer_norm(b_i), 2, 3) 
            Z.append(torch.transpose(linear_layer(b_i), 2, 3))


        Z = torch.stack(Z, 3)
        return Z
```

```
### Tensorflow code
    def call(self, x):
        output = []
        # split input tensor into freq bands
        for i, (start, end) in enumerate(zip(self.idxs[:-1], self.idxs[1:])):
            subband = x[:, :, :, start:end]
            # print subband shape
            print(subband.shape)


            # store output subband tensor after ln and linear transformation
            subband = self.layer_norms[i](subband)
            subband = tf.transpose(subband, perm=[0, 1, 3, 2])

            # pass transposed tensor through the linear layer, then transpose the output back to the original shape
            subband = self.linear_layers[i](subband)
            subband = tf.transpose(subband, perm=[0, 1, 3, 2])

            output.append(subband)
```

I have attempted writing line by line the exact pytorch code with identical tensorflow functions but it hasnt worked, so I instead tried to just base myself off of the logic of the pytorch code and rewrite it in tensorflow. I think theres just a small piece missing, which I cannot find a solution for.